# NullPointerException from Toast while Unit Testing

Tags: android, junit, android-toast

I am testing a function of my Signup class, however every time I run it a NullPointerException occurs inside the first if statement it enters at:

```
pass.show()
```

I suspect it is has something to do with not testing the app with an emulator. How can I prevent errors of creating a Toast when I am testing this?

**Function in Signup Class:**

```
public boolean checkInput(String username, String email, String password, String confirmpassword) {
    if (!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".com")) {
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Email must be valid!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
        return false;
    }
    if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
        return false;
    }
    if (!(password.length() >= 6)) {
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password must be at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Test method:**

```
    @Test
    public void testInvalidEmail() {

    String testUser = "testUser";
    String testEmail = "testEmail.com"; //invalid
    String testPass = "testPass";
    String testConfirmPass = "testPass";

    assertFalse(signupClass.checkInput(testUser,testEmail,testPass,testConfirmPass));
}
```

Comment: please check this out and see if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to decouple `Toast` from your function. To do that, follow the below step, where I use your shown example and implement them exactly as per your need. Hopes this answer your inquiry, and you could able to follow through.

First create an interface for printing (toasting)

```
interface Printer {
    void print(String message);
}
```

Then make your `Signup` class implements the `Printer` decouple the `Toast` from your function. I believe your `Signup` is an `Activity`.

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity implements Printer {

    // ... other codes ...

    @Override
    public void print(String message) {
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Signup.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
    }
}
```

Then now, remove your `Toast` in your `checkInput` function, and perform the printing through the `printer` sent to the function

```
public boolean checkInput(String username, String email, String password, String confirmpassword, Printer printer) {
    if (!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".com")) {
        printer.print("Email must be valid!");
        return false;
    }
    if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
        printer.print("Passwords don't match!");
        return false;
    }
    if (!(password.length() >= 6)) {
        printer.print("Password must be at least 6 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: whichever function that calls `checkInput` from your class would need to send in the `Printer`, which is actually `this` if it is in `Signup` class e.g.

```
checkInput(testUser, testEmail, testPass, testConfirmPass, this)l;
```

Now in your test, just implement the Mock `Printer` e.g.

```
@Test
public void testInvalidEmail(MainActivity mainActivity) {

    String testUser = "testUser";
    String testEmail = "testEmail.com"; //invalid
    String testPass = "testPass";
    String testConfirmPass = "testPass";

    assertFalse(signUp.checkInput(testUser, testEmail, testPass, testConfirmPass, new Printer() {
        @Override
        public void print(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }));
}
```

With that, you could have your test done as per your desire, while your App still print through `Toast`

Comment: @Zeelee, please check this out and see if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped in my specific situation - my tests now work and don't run into this error anymore!

Comment: Thanks @Zeelee for accepting my answer. If this is good answer, maybe you could up vote it?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is UnitTesting then you need to decouple your code for the Android stuff (like Toast).

A way to go is create an interface to display a Toast (or handle any Android related component) so you can mock it.

For example:

```
public interface AndroidInteraction (){
    void showToast(Context context, String text, int length);
}
```

And implement that interface in your activity:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AndroidInteraction{
    .......
    ......

    @Override
    void showToast(Context context, String text, int length){
         Toast pass = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
         pass.show();
    }
```

And finally your Signup class should be aware of that interface, so you could pass it throw it's constructor:

```
AndroidInteraction androidInteraction;
public Signup (AndroidInteraction androidInteraction){
    this.androidInteraction = androidInteraction;
}
```

So your method now will look like (only one if clause to show how to use it, not the whole method):

```
if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
    androidInteraction.showToast(Signup.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return false;
}
```

And you will need to mock that interface in your test and pass it to the class constructor

Comment: Also you can remove **Context** from the showToast method and call **getApplicationContext()** when you override that method

Comment: Thanks, have upvoted - this is a great generic answer for anyone else that may run into this error!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the Toast on variable 'pass', just directly type 'Toast' and click the second suggestion.the  I also remove your return.

This is the problem that I've seen on your code:

Toast pass = Toast.makeText (.....);

if you want to put it on variable, do like this

```
Toast pass = new Toast(getContext());


pass.makeText (.....).show();
```

or

```
pass.makeText(....);
pass.show();
```

so my suggestion is the option to and try this:

```
public boolean checkInput(String username, String email, String password, String confirmpassword) {
if (!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".com")) {
    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Email must be valid!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
   Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
if (!(password.length() >= 6)) {
    Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password must be at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```